# Email Template usage for lead saved via web or manually

Tags: apex, workflow

I've created an email template HTML version in salesforce and populated with the lead.firstname & Lead.lastname. I am trying to send an email to the customer whose email address is saved in the email field of lead  if the leadsource = website. Please guide me on how to do so, is this achieved via Apex or Workflow if so any links to guide me this email should have the matter along with the name of the customer generated form xyz@insurance.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved via Workflow on Lead as:

1. Entry criteria as - When LeadSource is Website and Email field is not blank.
2. We can select the Workflow evaluation criteria that whether we need this workflow to work only on record creation or on edit as well.
3. Under the workflow actions, we select Email Alert and configure the same. We make sure that we have already created the email template with the desired content and we associate the same with the email alert.
4. In the Recipient option when configuring the Email Alert we will select the Email field, that you have mentioned.

Link to guide you step by step: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_wfalerts.htm&type=0

Let me know the queries!